# Error different in different environment for mysql + hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

In one environment for duplicate entries, I'm getting the exception like

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 3

and in another environment I'm getting it like

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'username_UNIQUE'

What might be the reason?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by the term "*environment*"? The exception  stack trace simply implies that you're violating the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Hi lion environment means production and local ...locally i have mysql 5.5 and on production i have mysql 5.0.x

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, both of them mean the same thing. It seems the mysql people have changed the error message. With the new version, they may have tried to make their messages more understandable and narrowed down. But as you can see, they haven't changed the exception class name. They have changed only the explanatory message. So if you ever want to google your exception, you should preferrably use the exception class name instead of the message.

In this case, the first message points directly at the 'value' of the key where it faces violation, and the second message points at the key 'column'.